# How to create Database connection in DataStage 8.5?

Tags: database-connection, etl, datastage, dbconnection

I have a very simple DataStage parallel job that does the following:

1. Extract data from a source DB
2. Transform one of the columns to a specific format
3. Load it to another target DB

My question: How to establish a DB connection for both source DB and target DB in this DataStage version 8.5?

And do I need to create a new parameter sets?

Answer (score 0):

The basic information like DB Name, Instanace, User Name, Password, Table Name, Insert Method are more than sufficient. Parameter Sets are to be keyed in only when your project / job explicitly defines the use of it.